# Can't install libapache2-mod-fastcgi and php-fpm

Tags: apt, apache2, php-fpm, fastcgi

So I am trying to install these two packages.
I first tried doing the following

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -yy apache2 libapache2-mod-fastcgi php-fpm
```

this returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-fastcgi
E: Unable to locate package php-fpm
```

So I then tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -yy apache2 
sudo apt-get install -yy libapache2-mod-fastcgi php-fpm
```

The apache2 will install but for the last line it still gives the same error.
I tried looking online if I was perhaps missing a repo, but I couldn't find anything that made me believe so.
Next to that I also changed my source.list to have multiverse behind any of them.
But this still did not work..
What might be the issue?

my source.list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main multiverse
```

After being redirected by one of you to a problem which explained I had to add the universe repo, I did the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
```

this gives the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libapache2-mod-fastcgi is not available, but is referred to by 
another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' has no installation candidate
```

I also tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
```

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt-get update` *again* after you changed the source.list?

Comment: `libapache2-mod-fastcgi php-fpm` package available in Universe Repository, enabled it, update your apt and install it again

Comment: @Jos Yes i did, but unfortunately it did not change a thing.

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri I added it and updated it according to the other question you included. Although it got me a step further a different error occurs now.

Comment: @user535733 I would like to thank you for linking the other question, but unfortunately it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Comments are intended to help you improve the question, not for conversation. Please update your question...by editing the question. Short responses like "It didn't work" and "a different error occurs now" do not provide enough information to help you - please edit your question with a more full description of exactly what has changed.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this problem by doing a Digital Ocean tutorial whilst trying to set-up an NGINX Apache2 reverse proxy. Turns out the tutorial was wrong and that `libapache2-mod-fastcgi` package isn't available in the Ubuntu repositories, so the command they gave was incorrect. It has to be obtained externally (at least now, maybe it was accurate before).

Funnily enough I found the correct way to do it in a different [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-18-04-server), which can be viewed below along with the source.

These commands worked for me:

```
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/liba/libapache-mod-fastcgi/libapache2-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libapache2-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Use like this, 

cd /tmp && wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/liba/libapache-mod-fastcgi/libapache2-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.2_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libapache2-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.2_amd64.deb; sudo apt install -f

Comment: i also came from the same source : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-16-04-server